# PaaS : How to build?

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee, saas, grails, paas

I wanted to make a web application through which :

- user(end user) can create his own 
  web application online.
- which will be    integrated with the
  databases and    application/web
  servers
- and user can also publish that
  application withing that application
  only...

Doing some research i come to know it goes under category of PaaS(Platform as a Service)

But i am confuse how can i do that ?
I want to build that application using Java/J2EE.

Can any one explain me from where should i start ?
Or which framework / technology is better to implement it in Java ?

Waiting for your helpful reply....

Comment: Could you be more precise? Will you allow users to submit/write their own Java/whatever code? Or do you want to create some sort of noob-friendly interface for creating simple applications through drag-and-drop and whatnot?

Comment: Hi...Igor, i want to allow users to make his/her own web applications through my Own aplication, and data will be stored at some central database server,means end user does not worry about the development environment setup...he only requires the laptop and internet connection only...:)

Comment: inlast comment "end user" (means "developer") need not worry about development environment setup for developing any web aplication in Java /J2EE...he can develop web application using the laptop and internet connection only...

Comment: Well, you could "easily" implement the whole user interface in GWT, however I'm not sure how you see the whole "developing your own web application" thingy - can the developers use whatever libraries, frameworks (let's say, within the same language)? That doesn't seem to feasible to me - almost every framework has different deployment steps, debugging enviroments, etc... Some start their own servers by default (like GWT).

Comment: i know my friend...for initial level we can implement this for any single framework(like:Struts), and single server(like:Apache tomcate) ad single database(like:MySQL) which all are open source..."whole" means:end users(Software Engineer) can develop their web application(Struts as a Framework,Apache tomcate as a server and MySQL as a database) through opening the "www.mydomain.com" from web browser...this is for your reference:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/what-platform-service-paas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options as far as choosing a PaaS - each PaaS vendor has its pros and cons, so you need to consider a range of issues:

- Language support - Do you want just Java or maybe additional languages/frameworks?
- Hosting - Are you going to use a cloud computing provider like Amazon Web Services? Or are you using your own hardware? Or do you want multiple options?
- DB support - You mentioned using a central DB. Do you plan on installing/administering this DB yourself, or use a hosted DB service? Do you need the PaaS to support the particular DB you want? Perhaps you need multiple Databases to provide scalability and separation among clients?

There are several good comparisons of PaaS vendors out there. This might be a good place to start: [Looking for PaaS providers recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542784/looking-for-paas-providers-recommendations)

Full disclosure: I work for [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org/), an Open-Source PaaS provider.

Answer (score 2):

I think while choosing a PaaS you should think of the below points.

1. It should be easy to deploy, scale and manage
2. Scaling
3. Flexible topology
4. Data safety
5. No vendor lock in
6. Open software stack

I suggest you, before going to any big vendor try a new player in town [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com). I recently used their services and continue to do so and they are just awesome. Their web UI is best in class and has no drama of API, SDK or downloadable software. Let me know if you use them so that I can also have some feedback before I migrate all our apps to them.

Surya

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you are looking for a solution that [Viravis](http://www.viravis.com) is currenlty implemented.

But believe me it is not an easy task to build that kind of platform. i strongly suggest you to look at some PaaS providers to get involved and build a business relationship to achieve your goal. They are just exists for this purpose. Provide platform for people who just want to develop a single online application or some professional who want to build an SaaS business.

I think it is better to hire the platform rather than build it from scratch (ofcourse if you dont have to...)

Answer (score -1):

A web application consists of language, framework, database and Web-server.

If you want to make a web application in java, you should try GRAILS framework.
Its fast and web development is very easy and you can use java code as it is, in it.

Secondly you can choose database from MySQL, PostgreSQL etc or if you want to use No-SQL dbs, you can choose from MOngoDB, CouchDB etc.

Web-Servers can be tomcat, jetty etc.

After creating you application, you would like to host your application on web, Here PaaS comes to play. It helps you to deploy and host your application on web. So what you have to do is only to focus on your application and then deploy your app on any PaaS providers.

There are many PaaS providers in market, you can choose any.