# Help emulating Heroku, GAE, etc : Building a web service privately (PaaS)

Tags: web-services, web-applications, heroku, cloud, cloud-hosting

I'm not the only one with this question, but haven't found a lot of information in my research so far, so help me out.

We are a small IT crowd in an organization. We're looking to build a small, private service that would emulate a heroku/gae workflow. The basics of this: deploy an app as a git repository, and have it scale in a 'cloud' environment. Basically, a platform as a service (Paas).

Pretend we are amateur PM's, programmers, and sysadmins tasked with this. What would you recommend? We know generally what is needed: some sort of routing, database, caching, authentication, etc. What other tools do we need?

We would prefer tools along a ruby/python/haskell/erlang dimension, on a linux/bsd stack, with postgres databases(couchdb or cassandra in the future). We are not touching anything in the ms/.net area, nothing on the JVM (We've looked at Steamcannon, but no; Scala and Clojure tools are not entirely out of the question). We have a basic grasp of bootstrapping a cloud (e.g. Eucalyptus) to build on. We have an understanding of the basics in server admin, and the physical infrastructure limitations aren't a factor right now.

*We're not looking into why gaerokuyardspace is the best choice, a list of such services, why we should ditch our plans for one of these services, or an argument against this plan. For this situation the decision has been made that the cost to build privately is more attractive than the cost of deploying elsewhere. We already know why and how for these services. We're looking to emulate and build upon these for private needs.*

A short list of tools to be expanded:

- Beehive
- Steamcannon
- Gitosis/Gitolite
- ?

Basically, I'd like to generate a list of tools for building heroku/gae like service on a small, private, definitely experimental/toy level.

Comment: If it is a dumb question, it is a dumb question.

Comment: see also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458409/paas-how-to-build

Comment: http://blog.mccrory.me/2011/01/23/current-paas-patterns-types-of-paas/

Comment: Maybe you wann include this in your list http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/ It's supposed to be an Open Source GAE clone from what I can tell. Never tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it will meet all of your stated needs today, but you should take a look at [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/) from VMware. You can check the [FAQ](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/faq) for the commercial project or look in to the [Open Source version](http://cloudfoundry.org/) that you can host and manage yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of Cloud Foundry (above) [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), and [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.4/index.html) 
will probably do well for you.  Any such solution will take some time to get right.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm a lead developer on the AppScale project)

[AppScale](http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu) is pretty much right up your alley, especially if you're looking to run Google App Engine apps in your own private cloud. It's open source, so grab it and extend it if there are other types of apps you want to support (and definitely commit it back to us if you do).