# Any good online deployment automation and management tool?

Tags: deployment, open-source, automation, cloud

I'd like to offer my customers a click-to-install/click-to-activate option to let them get their Magento/Custom Webapp online without manual installation based on my server configuration templates/custom virtual appliances. I know this could be done by certain scripts, but what I want is a web solution, preferably written in PHP.

I found standingcloud.com provides exactly what I want but with additional monthly charge comparable to the server cost. It's also not convenient to push customized web applications into customer console.

Is there any similar open source deployment automation & management system supporting amazon ec2/rackspace/linode and multiple custom web applications?

There are a lot of open source IaaS products for data centers or hosting companies building cloud infrastructures.

But I didn't get any clue of similar open source PaaS products for ISVs or service providers building development platforms.

SaaS is good enough for some clients. But many customers only want managed open source web applications hosted on their selected servers to avoid vendor lock-in. That's kind of "private saas".

Any suggestion? 
   Thank you for sharing.

Comment: This question comes very first in the google search. Adding a useful link here, even though this does not answer original question : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software

Comment: It's so sad these tools are mainly made by Ruby or Python. It seems PHP developers are scattered everywhere but not in the domains critical to the future.

Answer (score 2):

ComodIT (http://comodit.com) has a feature enabling you to add a one-click deployment button directly on your site. They also provide a free cloud platform for your users to test your application. I do not know of any open source equivalent, but if all you need is a free service that enable your users to easily deploy your application with your configurations, this should do the trick.

Here is what the integration looks like on one of my open source projects: http://storytlr.org/

Disclosure: I'm co-founder and software architect of ComodIT

Answer (score 0):

There's a good comparison of PaaS offerings here: [Looking for PaaS providers recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542784/looking-for-paas-providers-recommendations)

Disclaimer: I work for Gigaspaces, developer of the Cloudify open source PaaS.
Cloudify is developed with Java but allows you to run any native process you want, and supports multiple clouds. There is an apache httpd recipe available here:
https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify-recipes/tree/master/services/apache

You can use the Cloudify CLI or REST API to deploy applications.