# Cloud Agnostic Tool On Any IaaS Based Cloud

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, openstack, aws-cloudformation

Is there any technology like CloudFormation for aws that would work on any IaaS based cloud to do the same thing? I mean you write it once and then it runs on any IaaS based cloud platform like azure, aws, openstack, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is exactly OpenStack Heat Project http://wiki.openstack.org/Heat The project is under active development.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is making some assumptions that isn't quite correct - there's a lot of different types of clouds - Google AppEngine, OpenShift, Heroku and Azure (for example) work at a very different layer than the cloud services you get from Amazon AWS, CloudStack, OpenStack, etc.

The first is more of an platform as a service (PaaS) play, the later are more infrastructure as a service (IaaS). That said, and given that you're asking about Amazon's CloudFormation, it's worth mentioning that there's an equivalent of that technology for OpenStack clouds called [HEAT](http://heat-api.org) (although I'm not aware of one that works with CloudStack).

To answer you're higher level of question of "is there a way to write it once and run it on any cloud?", today the answer is a qualified "no". There's lots of APIs and helper libraries you can use to bring several cloud provider options more into compatibility, and some companies are making all their pennies of exactly this game (enStratus, for example). But none of them go so far as to allow you to "run it anywhere" - especially when you lump IaaS style clouds in with PaaS style clouds.

Comment: After the MeetWindowsAzure event (June 2012), Azure became both PaaS and IaaS. So in WIndows Azure you can also get the same IaaS services that you would get from Amazon, ...

Comment: Sorry I should have been specific as I only meant for IaaS based clouds. So basically the ability for me to describe my infrastructural and depending on what IaaS based cloud I chose, deployment happen with same code. Any specific stack that allows that?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS) that works on multiple clouds. There is a similar question here: [Cloud Mangement for Amazon IaaS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305454/cloud-mangement-for-amazon-iaas)

The answers also link to a comparison of PaaS options.

Answer (score 0):

Check out enstratus.  It's a UI for interfacing with multiple Cloud APIs.  So you can store and shift images between different clouds then spin them up and down.  Might be what you want.