# amazon automated management and monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We are getting ready to deploy a new app in the Amazon cloud, using EC2, RDS, and elastic load balancers. RDS would be sharded. Looking at the difficulties of manageing and monitoring anything beyond a few servers, one  can see how quickly the task could become pretty crazy. Amazon's interfaces allow you to do all this, but we would have to script it all ourselves.

I was wondering what others have done. There is RightScale, for managed solutions. Has anyone found any other companies, or open source frame works, that do this kind of thing? Looking at:

Monitoring EC2, load balancers, RDS.
Spinning up new instances of the above automatically on predefined load levels.
Sending alerts and taking resources offline automatically when thesholds occur.
Promoting new software/upgrades in PHP and MySQL.
Taking numbers of servers offline for maintenance/troubleshooting.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The type of services you are looking for - automated provisioning, scaling in/out and monitoring is generally referred as PaaS - Platform as a Service. The idea is that you submit your application to the PaaS system and it manages the complete life-cycle of your application.

There are several PaaS providers available that might fit your needs. There's a comparison available here: [Looking for PaaS providers recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542784/looking-for-paas-providers-recommendations)

You should consider your requirements carefully and see which provider is right for you in terms of:

- Cloud Support: Do you need just EC2 or maybe additional clouds?
- Language support: Some providers target specific coding frameworks and languages
- Support
- Pricing
- Open/Closed source

Disclaimer: I work for GigaSpaces, developer of the [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org) open-source PaaS Stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [scalr](https://scalr.net/). They offer this services on their own platform but you can also download the software they're using and set it up on your own.

After Amazon EC2 they started expanding into other cloud services as well, so you can run your scalr managed instances on literally all huge cloud providers.

Very [feature rich](https://scalr.net/features/), but so far I haven't tested it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Xervmon. They offer integrated cloud management suite of tools to deploy, manage, monitor Amazon AWS along with several other providers. They do offer managed services as well.