# How to install/configure new software in newly created amazon instances using Amazon SDK in java?

Tags: amazon-ec2

My team is developing an application which will enable end users to easily create, configure and destroy amazon instances without having to use Amazon SDKs themselves. The process at our end comprises of 3 steps.
1. Create / Destroy VMs in the amazon cloud using Amazon SDK (Done)
2. Configure/Install new software in the newly created instance.
3. Track usage/command and control.

We are currently in the second step. I just realized that Amazon SDK does not provide APIs for installing new software in the remote machine. I am not talking about AmazonCloudFormation APIs because those APIs are used to create and manage AWS resources rather a software like, say, a browser.

Has anyone installed new software in an amazon instance? If yes, did you use one of  a)Amazon SDK, b) Any third party APIs and c) custom solution? 
Also, is it even possible to install new software in an amazon instance through java code?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon API primarily controls infrastructure. It does not have any control as to what happens inside the instance.

There are a couple of ways you can bootstrap your instance and install software. You can use user-data to pass a script that will run on first launch. You could use a provisioning system like chef or puppet. You could roll your own if it works better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We (my team) are also discussing the above options, especially using a provisioning system like puppet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds a lot like a Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS).

A PaaS would allow you to submit an application to the PaaS and let it start the machines and set up your software on them. A PaaS would also give you additional features like monitoring, cross-cloud support and updating the application on the fly.

There are a several PaaS vendors mentioned here: [Looking for Paas Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542784/looking-for-paas-providers-recommendations)

Disclaimer: I work for [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org), an open-source PaaS.